# Count Values under Columns with Same Name Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count

I have a Google sheet which has columns with the same name and there are different values under each column. I want to count the same value that appear under the same column name.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | B | C | R | D |
| D | C | R | B | D |

For example, I would like to get the number "R" that appear under column "1", so I would expect a count of 2 for "R" appearing under columns 1.

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B1E4L8mT9e3eAClfUN3WYtDOjZCWJfFxke-OvKKOLDU/edit?usp=sharing) to Google Sheet with actual data.

I have tried countif and countifs in Google Sheets, but can't figure out how to get the count right based on column name.

Comment: Try this formula and let me know your feedback `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:AE1=1)*(A2:AE18="R"))`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: sample]

Try this formula, it outputs an array which shows how many of each letters are contained in each column name:

```
=LAMBDA(NUMBERS,LETTERS,
 LAMBDA(UNUM,ULET,
  {
   {"",TRANSPOSE(UNUM)};
   {ULET,
    MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(ULET),COUNTA(UNUM),LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
     COUNTIF(FILTER(LETTERS,NUMBERS=INDEX(UNUM,COL)),INDEX(ULET,ROW))
    ))
   }
  }
 )(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(NUMBERS)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(LETTERS)))
)($A$1:$AE$1,$A$2:$AE$18)
```

Assume that your sample datarange is `A1:AE18`.

1. apply `UNIQUE()` and `FLATTEN()` to `A1:AE1`, to get the unique entries of column names.
2. apply `UNIQUE()` and `FLATTEN()` to `A2:AE18`, to get the unique entries of data.
3. use `LAMBDA()` to name the dataranges and output of step 1 & 2 as:

   - `NUMBERS` (`=A1:AE1`),
   - `LETTERS` (`=A2:AE18`),
   - `UNUM` (`=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(NUMBERS))`),
   - `ULET` (`=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(LETTERS))`).
4. create Arrays with `{}`, which...

   - 1st column's value is a blank, followed by `TRANSPOSE(UNUM)` in the row,
   - 1st row's value is a blank, followed by `ULET` in the column.
   - inside the above said range, use `MAKEARRAY()` to create results.
5. `MAKEARRAY()` set an array by defining the length of `ROW` and `COL`, which we uses...

   - `COUNTA(ULET)` as the number of rows and,
   - `COUNTA(UNUM)` as the number of columns.
6. inside `MAKEARRAY()`, you also need a `LAMBDA()` to apply what to do with each `CELL` of the new created array, each `CELL` is accessed by the `ROW` and `COL` index.
7. in our case, we set up the row and col number of the new array using `ULET` and `UNUM`. Therefor, the index of each `CELL` of the new array will be equal to the index of each value inside `ULET` and `UNUM`, we can than take that as reference and use `COUNTIF()` with `FILTER()` to calculate the number of repeats of each letter in each column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(
    query(
        query(
            SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
                    QUERY(
                        TRANSPOSE(
                            QUERY(
                                TRANSPOSE(
                                    IF(Original!A2:AE18<>"",
                                        ""&Original!A1:AE1&"♥"&Original!A2:AE18, )
                                ),,999^99)
                        ),,999^99),
                    "")),
                "♥"),
            "Select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) group by Col1,Col2"),
        "Select max(Col2),Col3 group by Col2,Col3 pivot Col1")
)
```

**Note**: (Got inspired by player0 useful answers)

**Output**:

[image]

We can read from the table that: R is appearing 40 times under the column named '1', 24 times under the colum named '2', etc...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9fwX.png

Comment: Wonderful, why reinventing the wheek. This is why I like this forum, it helps you remove sophisticated thinkings that can be accomplished by much simpler solutions

Answer (score 0):

The following is a more compact approach than the previous answers:

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(A1:AE1&"|"&A2:AE18),"|"),"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

N.B. I'm assuming the order of the grouped values in each column is irrelevant, so the QUERY default of lexicographical ordering is fine.